# Pandas, convert long name date to short form

Tags: pandas

I have an input of a date and want to convert it to its short form. Ie. `August 2021` to `Aug 2021`

`monthyear = input("Enter Month and Year: ")`

How can I convert `monthyear` to its abbreviated version in pandas?

What i've tried:

`smalldate = monthyear.strftime("%b %y")`

getting `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'`

Also tried:

`smalldate = dt.datetime.strftime(monthyear, "%b %y")`

with error
`TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse the string input to a `datetime` before using `strftime`.

Try:

```
monthyear = input("Enter Month and Year: ")
smalldate = pd.to_datetime(monthyear, format="%B %Y").strftime("%b %Y")
```